# Calculating field with input from two layers in QGIS Graphical Modeler

Tags: qgis, layers, fields-attributes, attribute-joins, qgis-modeler

Even though I found similar questions, I couldn't find a suitable answer for the problem I have.

I want to create a model that calculates the difference between two fields (`"NUMPOINTS"`) from different vector files and populate a new field with the result in a new vector file.

My input are 2 vector layers: *'Events A'* and *'Events B'*. These tables have the same fields, including a common `"id"` field.

I need to create a *'Table C'* where `"DIFFERENCE"` field is calculated as follow: `"NUMPOINTS"` (*'Table B'*) - `"NUMPOINTS"` (*'Table A'*)

So far, I managed to create a Join, but I don't know how to create a new field with input from the two input files.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the fieldcalculator in your model to do the calculation:

[image]

since your fields have the same name "NUMPOINTS" you can use a prefix for the joind NUMPOINTS field in the JOIN operation:

[image]

the formula in the fieldcalculator would be:

[image]

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: if this answer is a solution to your question you can mark the answer as accepted...